# How to write the test cases using enzyme for the MENU ITEM using google material UI

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

Following are code snippets for the testing with react-enzyme.

const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

```
<Popper
          id="More-Options"
          anchorEl={anchorEle}
          open={this.state.open}
          placement="left-start"
        >
          <Paper id="paper">
            {options.map(option => (
              <MenuItem

                className={classes.menuStyle}
                key={option.name}
                //selected={option === "Option1"}
                onClick={(event: any) => this.handleClose(option.action, event)}
              >
                {option.name}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Paper>
        </Popper>
```

Here i am having the code for the MenuItem using google materail UI ,When click on that it will displays the option1 and option2

I tried using the following way using react enzyme.

```js
it('should toggle state', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Component{...props} />);
        const menuItem = wrapper.find(MenuItem);
        menuItem.simulate("click", { currentTarget: "" });
                
    });
```

But how it would be check if the user clicks onto the option1 and option2.
I tried using only with enzyme.

Cheers,